# Como fazer um helper de usuário logado em Asp.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou precisando implementar um Helper para usuário logado, ou seja uma classe estática que devolva informações sobre o usuário logado do `context`. A ideia é usar as informações tanto em `Controllers` quanto em `Views`.

Comment: O que seria um helper de usuário logado?

Comment: Você precisa dar mais detalhes! O que quer que o helper faça? E de onde ele vai consumir dados?

Comment: Preciso ficar rico!

Comment: Você ta usando Entity Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@LuizNegrini você pode tentar usar um singleton na classe ProfessionalUser. Adicionando uma propriedade estática do mesmo tipo da classe, quando chamada você pode buscar o usuário atual através de outro método externo e usando como parâmetro o id do usuário, criptografado, em um cookie ou na sessão.

```
namespace Aplicacao.Model
{
    public class ProfessionalUser
    {
        private static ProfessionalUser _user;
        private static string _keyUser = "idUserOuQualquerChaveQueVoceEscolher";

        public int IdProfessionalUser { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string ReEmail { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string RePassword { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int IdProfessionalRegister { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        public int Phone { get; set; }

        public static ProfessionalUser UsuarioAtual
        {
            get
            {
                if(_user == null)
                {
                    int idUser = 0;
                    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.current.Request.Cookies[_keyUser];
                    string v = cookie != null ? cookie.Value : String.Empty;
                    int.TryParse(v, out idUser);
                    _user = (new QualquerGerenciadorDeUsuario()).FuncaoQuePegaOUsuarioPeloID(idUser);
                }
                return _user;
            }
            set
            {
                int idUser = 0;
                if(value != null && value.ID > 0)
                {
                    idUser = value.ID;
                    _user = value;
                }else
                    _user = null;

                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(_keyUser, idUser.ToString());
                HttpContext cxt = HttpContext.current;
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddHours(3);// o cookie vale por 3 horas
                cxt.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Já na `View`, você pode chamar o a propriedade a qualquer momento de duas formas:

```
@Aplicacao.Model.ProfessionalUser.UsuarioAtual
```

E a partir daí você pode pegar toda e qualquer propriedade do usuário atual:

@Aplicacao.Model.ProfessionalUser.UsuarioAtual.IdProfessionalUser

A outra forma é incluindo o `namespace` na `View`:

```
@using Aplicacao.Model
@ProfessionalUser.UsuarioAtual
```

... e as propriedades é do mesmo jeito:

```
@ProfessionalUser.UsuarioAtual.IdProfessional
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Att,
Uilque Messias

Answer (score 2):

Segue um `Helper` que fiz para pegar informações do usuário logado.

Este projeto utiliza `Membership`, ou seja, é uma abordagem antiga, mas que serve como exemplo para melhoramentos no caso do ASP.NET Identity:

```
public static class LoggedUserHelper
{
    private static MyProjectContext context = new MyProjectContext();

    public static UserProfile CurrentUserInfo(IPrincipal User) {
        int currentUserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
        return context.UserProfile.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == currentUserId);
    }

    public static int UserId(IPrincipal User) {
        return WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
    }

    public static int UserId(String UserName) {
        return WebSecurity.GetUserId(UserName);
    }

    ...
}
```

Obviamente meu Model `UserProfile` tem várias colunas adicionais, mas vou colocar apenas o mínimo necessário pra funcionar:

```
public class UserProfile {
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: O "MyProjectContext" seria o DataContext do projeto em sí? Não ficou claro, que devo fazer.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Isso. Na verdade o que o Helper faz é reunir uma porção de comandos juntos que você teria que invocar para obter dados de um usuário, não apenas do logado. Pode ser de outros usuários, inclusive.